# how to use json feeders in gatling when the json structure is complicated

Tags: gatling

In the scenario, how to give the EL$ for the field 'location' and 'ID'.

I tried giving as below but getting error as Attribute not defined for 'ID' and 'Location'

```scala
 .body(
   StringBody(
     """{"name": "${name}", "Url": "${Url}", “Product”: [ { "ID": "${ID}", "location": "${location}" } ] }"""
   )
  ).asJson
```

JSON:

```json
[
   {
      "name":"xyz",
      "url":"test1.com",
      "Product":[
         {
            "ID":111111,
            "location":"NewYork"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"abc",
      "url":"test2.com",
      "Product":[
         {
            "ID":22222,
            "location":"Texas"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: There's no way to help you if you don't provide your JSON's structure.

Comment: Below is how the JSON structure looks like 

{
  "name": “xyz”,
  “url": "https://test1.com",
  “Product”: [
    {
      "ID": 111111,
       "location": “NewYork”
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @ Stéphane LANDELLE  Thank u very much. I have provided the structure in my previous comment

Comment: @Stéphane LANDELLE
This is how my feeder file looks like :

[

{
  "name": “xyz”,
  “url": "https://test1.com",
  “Product”: [
    {
      "ID": 111111,
       "location": “NewYork”
    }
  ]
},


{
  "name": “abc”,
  “url": "https://test2.com",
  “Product”: [
    {
      "ID": 22222,
       "location": “Texas”
    }
  ]
}


]  I face the issue  Attribute not defined for 'ID' and 'Location' when i try to use $ for the ID & location field in string body i

Comment: @Stéphane LANDELLE.    Tried based on your advice .But its not picking the values from the json feeder.
.body(StringBody("""{
                           "name": "${name}",
                            "Url": "${Url}",
                           “product”: [
                           {
                                "ID": #{product.ID},

                               "location": #{product.location}
                              }
                             ]
                           }"""))

Comment: @Stéphane LANDELLE.  
In the  logs, observing that the request body gets constructed as below after picking from feeder and results in 400 error:
                                   "name": “xyz”,
                                    "Url": "https://test1.com",
                                   “product”: [
                                   {
                                        "ID": #{product.ID},
                                        "location": #{product.location}
                                      }
Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: @Stéphane LANDELLE.        I even tried giving within quotes as  " #{product.ID}" in StringBody but doesnt work

Comment: Then, take some time to provide a proper reproducer as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

The `ID` and `location` fields are inside a `Product` object, so the correct Gatling EL String would be respectively `#{Product.ID}` and `#{Product.location}`.